# Logical Inference Question, I disagree with the answer

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

Apologies for the generic title, couldn't find a better one. So the question is as follows:

Given the following statements, determine which of these conclusions follow:

> **Statements:**
>
> - All laptops are computers
> - Some phones are computers
> - Some desktops are computers
> - Some desktops are phones
>
> **Conclusions:**
>
> 1. Some laptops are phones
> 2. No desktop is a laptop
> 3. Some desktops are both computers and phones
> 4. Some phones are desktops alone

The answer is that #4 is the only valid conclusion. I disagree with this, and their reasoning for it is as follows:

> #4 is valid because some desktops are phones. Not all are joined together with computers..

Uhm, no? We don't know that not all are joined together with computers. The way I see it there are three possibilities, **bold** is my addition:

- Case 1: Some desktops are computers, some desktops are phones, **no desktops are both computers and phones**
- Case 2: Some desktops are computers, some desktops are phones, **some desktops are both computers and phones, some desktops are phones alone**
- Case 3: Some desktops are computers, some desktops are phones, **some desktops are both computers and phones, no desktops are phones alone**

Case 3 means that conclusion #4 *could* be false. That would look something like this (pardon the poor photoshop):

[image: Case 3]

Am i missing something here? Why is the venn diagram above somehow not possible? Statement #4 still holds. Some desktops *are* phones, but they also happen to always also be computers. We don't know this for sure, but we know that it may be true, which would make Conclusion 4 not necessarily true

Comment: If this is from a book (as opposed to an in-class exercise), can you say which one?

Comment: ... So that I can avoid it and recommend others do the same, of course. :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### This is a horrible problem.

First of all, even before we start solving things note that $4$ is ambiguous: what does "desktop *alone*" mean? Maybe it means "desktop but not laptop," but "desktop but not laptop or computer" is also within the bounds of imagination. This is a nit-pick, **but we are doing logic after all**.

Secondly, the answer - as you observe - is wrong. The easiest way to see this in my opinion is to note that *no hypothesis gives any negative information*. In particular, the hypotheses listed don't rule out the possibility that phones=computers=desktops=laptops, which of course would make *any* interpretation of $4$ false. Now maybe we're supposed to assume that every computer is either a desktop or a laptop but not both, but that assumption hasn't actually been stated - and as above, this is a terrible thing to do **in a class/book about logic**.

> To be honest, I don't immediately see a non-silly way to construe the problem so that the given "solution" is valid.

*(This all assumes the problem has been copied correctly, of course - the obvious potential issue is if you've omitted hypotheses made earlier in the text which have - perhaps tacitly - continued to be assumed.)*

Comment: Unfortunately, it is correctly copied and I wholeheartedly agree with you. They use the word "alone" a lot in these questions, and it's always ambiguous. This is from a "test-prep" website which prepares you for the [HFMTalentIndex](https://www.hfm.nl/nl/) assessment test, which is used as part of an interview process. Glad to know I'm not crazy